# Pull Request Template - Only See Comments In the Template When Creating

Tags: github, azure-devops

I need to write some comments in a GitHub PR template that will *only* be visible to the person who is creating (or editing) the PR, but will not be not visible on the pull request description once it's created/edited.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that. But a solution would be to create a GitHub Action that triggers when a pull request is created and then adds a private comment to the pull request to the user who created it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using HTML comments - see below. The comment will only be visible when creating or editing the PR description.

```markdown
# My PRE template

My template

<!-- My private comment -->

The rest of the template
```

Another option would be to use a GitHub Action to scan the PR description and remove some of it via pattern matching. This GitHub Action is an example of that pattern: https://github.com/luigibertaco/dynamic-template-action

The advantage of HTML comments is that they will continue to be visible later when re-editing the PR description.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a test that checks the template text doesn't exists on any files.
This would be paired with a practice of PR reviews being started after all tests are passing

Comment: The question is about comments in the PR template itself